Accepting suggestion by pressing tab in vscode extension development
const acceptSuggestionCmd = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "frost.acceptSuggestion",
    async () => {
      if (currentSuggestion) {
        isAcceptingSuggestion = true;
        console.log("tab key detected");
        await acceptSuggestion();
        isAcceptingSuggestion = false;
        return true;
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(acceptSuggestionCmd);

vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((event) => {
    if (event.document === activeEditor?.document) {
      const change = event.contentChanges[0];
      if (change.text !== "\t") {
        console.log("something else is pressed");
        clearSuggestion();
      }
    }
  });

for package.json

      {
        "command": "frost.acceptSuggestion",
        "title": "Accept Suggestion"
      }
    ],
    "keybindings": [
      {
        "command": "frost.acceptSuggestion",
        "key": "tab",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && frost.hasSuggestion",
      }
    ]


In the above code, I am trying to make an inline extension where users can accept it by pressing tab. As per the above code when i run the extension and test it, on pressing tab, it performs the tab's default function and cancels the suggestion. On debugging, I find out that the command due to the keybind never runs instead what runs first is the onDidChangeTextDocument, then I try to limit it by trying the above code and check if its not the tab key and then only clear suggestion, however I find out that the tab key is not identified properly as on pressing tab, in the console i  see "something else is pressed" even when i pressed tab. There are no errors in the console and yep this is all.
What I tried:

Tried the function onDidChangeTextEditorSelection, though it worked but not for just tab but any key that I pressed and it pasted the content twice, so that didnt work out well and I found out there was apparantely no way to check what key was pressed.

Tried using the 'type' register command method however there aswell it didnt work. I think the problem is in identifying whether the tab key is pressed or not and I think there is some other way to do it which im unknown of.

Tried both register command and registerTextCommand.


What I was expecting to happen:
Simply, I want the suggestion to get accepted and inserted into the user's current cursor position when he/she presses tab only if a current suggestion exists, if it doesnt let user type normally.
